# On a Windows CE computer, in the Registry Editor, where would one find the equivalent of the Winlogon folder?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-ce

On a Windows Vista computer, the path to the winlogon folder is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

The key of interest in the Winlogon folder is Userinit. I want to see if it points to userinit.exe or to some other file, which might be a virus.

On the Windows CE computer, I only see:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
```

There is no Windows NT.